# Closest point on a circle using the maxima and minima concept in solving extremum problem

Tags: calculus

I'm stuck at this Calculus problem. The question asks to find the closest point on a circle of radius $1$ to the black dot as shown in the figure:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please add more context to the problem. A mere problem-statement question will not be well-received on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P = (x,y)$ be the point on the unit circle centered at the origin and $Q = (-2,1)$ be the black point you are talking about...then we minimize $PQ^2= (x+2)^2+(y-1)^2= 4x-2y+6$ such that $x^2+y^2=1$. We have $|4x-2y|\le \sqrt{(4^2+2^2)(x^2+y^2)}=2\sqrt{5}\implies -2\sqrt{5}\le 4x-2y\le 2\sqrt{5}\implies PQ_{\text{min}}=\sqrt{6-2\sqrt{5}}=\sqrt{5}-1$. The minimum value occurs when $\dfrac{4}{x}=\dfrac{-2}{y}\implies x = -2y\implies P=(x,y) = (-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}})$ .

Answer (score 7):

Hint: closest point lies on the line, connecting the center of the circle and this point. Proven by triangle inequality.

Answer (score 2):

Closest point to the circle is the intersection of the line joining the point with the origin and the circle. The equation of line joining the point with the origin $\Big($calculated using $y=mx+c$ or $\dfrac{y-y_1}{y_2-y_1}=\dfrac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1}$$\Big)$ gives you $x=-2y$. So to find the intersection $(-2y)^2+y^2=1\implies y=\pm\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$. So the required point is $\left(\dfrac{-2}{\sqrt{5}},\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right)$ and the distance is $\sqrt{6-2\sqrt{5}}$.